# jumping average column at every n-th rows

Tags: r, split, average, intervals

Please help me on this..
so I have daily observations (data frame) for 32-year period. (thus total around 11659 rows: there's some missing rows) 
I want to calculate average of each column at every 365th interval (i.e. every jan-01 for 32 year period, every Jan-02 for 32 year period, etc.

so the output would have total 365 rows and each row is average of 32 rows at 365 interval.
any suggestions? I found similar case and tried their solution and modified a bit but the output is not correct. especially I don't understand sapply part below..

```
df <-data.frame(x=c(1:10000),y=c(1:10000))
byapply <- function(x, by, fun, ...)
{
# Create index list
if (length(by) == 1)
{
    nr <- nrow(x)
    split.index <- rep(1:ceiling(nr / by), each = by, length.out = nr)
} else 
{
    nr <- length(by)
    split.index <- by
}
index.list <- split(seq(from = 1, to = nr), split.index)

# Pass index list to fun using sapply() and return object #this is where I am lost
sapply(index.list, function(i)
        {
            do.call(fun, list(x[, i], ...))
        })
}
```

thank you for your time..

Comment: index.list<-split(seq(from = 1, to = nr),split.index) that line also seemed not correct to me...

Comment: If you are using the weather observations, how to deal with leap years? It will be better to generate some new columns for your data, actually date, day of year. Then you can use apply function.

Comment: yes, that's also issue i got too. I need to reassemble my data, thanks for comments.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `plyr` package:

```
require(plyr)    # for aggregating data

require(plyr)    # for aggregating data

series<-data.frame(date=as.Date("1964-01-01")+(1:100000),
                   obs=runif(10000),
                   obs2=runif(10000),
                   obs3=runif(10000))

ddply(series,                     # run on series df
      .(DOY=format(date,"%j")),   # group by string of day and month (call col DOY)
      summarise,                  # tell the function to summarise by group (day of year)
      daymean=mean(obs),          # calculate the mean
      daymean2=mean(obs2),        # calculate the mean
      daymean3=mean(obs3)         # calculate the mean
)

#    DOY   daymean  daymean2  daymean3
#1   001 0.4957763 0.4882559 0.4944281
#2   002 0.5184197 0.4970996 0.4720893
#3   003 0.5192313 0.5185357 0.4878891
#4   004 0.4787227 0.5150596 0.5317068
#5   005 0.4972933 0.5065012 0.4956527
#6   006 0.5112484 0.5276013 0.4785681
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there's possibly a special function, which does exactly what you need, here is a solution using `ave`:

```
set.seed(1)
dates = seq(from=as.Date("1970-01-01"), as.Date("2000-01-01"), by="day")
df <- data.frame(val1=runif(length(dates)), 
                 val2=rchisq(length(dates), 10))
day <- format(dates, "%j") # day of year (1:366)

df <- cbind(df, setNames(as.data.frame(sapply(df, function(x) {
  ave(x, day) # calculate mean by day for df$val1 and df$val2
})), paste0(names(df), "_mean")))

head(df[1:365, 3:4], 3)
#   val1_mean val2_mean
# 1 0.5317151 10.485001
# 2 0.5555664 10.490968
# 3 0.6428217 10.763027
```

That is, if I understood your task correctly.